# If you build with Android L you can't run your app on older versions of Android

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm trying to get material design working on my app so I created a values-v21 folder and have the following in my styles.xml file:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#333333</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#fa6900</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

This gives me the following error unless I set my build target to Android L:

*Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar'*

After changing my build target to Android L, the error goes away but doing so gives me the following error:

*Platform L is a preview and requires application manifest to set minSdkVersion to 'L'  AndroidManifest.xml*

Is there anyway to use Material Design and have a minsdkversion lower than "L"?

Comment: material theme is not available in support library as of now so this is expected

Comment: Hence the "preview" part, you may not want to ship your app that supports L and APIs below it, as it may change.

Comment: Okay, so is there currently no way to ship an app with material design without making it dev preview exclusive?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't dive into L preview deeply, but initially I think you can grab some xml files as well as drawables from your SDK folder.

The SDK folder you should look into lies in:

`SDK_PATH/platforms/android-L/data/res/values`

`SDK_PATH/platforms/android-L/data/res/drawables` and etc

like this:

"styles_material.xml"

```
<style name="Widget.Material.Button.Toggle">
    <item name="background">@drawable/btn_toggle_material</item>
    <item name="textOn">@string/capital_on</item>
    <item name="textOff">@string/capital_off</item>
    <item name="minHeight">48dip</item>
</style>
```

and you can follow the route to find `btn_toggle_material` inside `drawable` folder.

"btn_toggle_material.xml"

```
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:insetLeft="4dp"
    android:insetTop="4dp"
    android:insetBottom="4dp"
    android:insetRight="4dp">
    <layer-list android:paddingMode="stack">
        <item>
            <ripple android:color="?attr/colorControlHighlight">
                <item>
                    <nine-patch android:src="@drawable/btn_toggle_mtrl_alpha"
                        android:tint="?attr/colorButtonNormal" />
                </item>
            </ripple>
        </item>
        <item>
            <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
                <item android:state_checked="false">
                    <nine-patch android:src="@drawable/btn_toggle_indicator_mtrl_alpha"
                        android:tint="?attr/colorControlNormal" />
                </item>
                <item android:state_checked="true">
                    <nine-patch android:src="@drawable/btn_toggle_indicator_mtrl_alpha"
                        android:tint="?attr/colorControlActivated" />
                </item>
            </selector>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
</inset>
```

It is a tedious job but some people did similar job to make "Holo Everwhere" library in the "Holo Style" era.

Hope it helps.